# sinatra-authentication gem not looking for correct views?

Tags: ruby, authentication, view, sinatra, mongoid

I am attempting to write a small blogging engine for myself in sinatra and mongoid and am trying to use the [sinatra-authentication gem](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/) to do login/out.

I have gotten sinatra, mongoid, and haml all working but when I visit any sinatra-authentication page nginx throws an internal server error.

this is the error I am getting

```
Errno::ENOENT - No such file or directory -     /opt/nginx/html/raptor.patrickarlt.com/views/layout.haml:
```

you can see all my files including more from my nginx error log here https://gist.github.com/854156

get '/' works confirming Sinatra is working
get '/haml' works confirming haml is working
get '/private' redirects to '/login' confirming sinatra-authentication is working
get '/login' internal server error

Ruby 1.9.2
Nginx 0.8.54
Passenger 3.0.2

Comment: Does `/opt/nginx/html/raptor.patrickarlt.com/views/layout.haml` actually exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sinatra-authentication` assumes you're using a layout unless the current request is an XMLHttpRequest (see [the code](https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication/blob/master/lib/sinatra-authentication.rb#L217-219)). You have two options:

1. Create a layout for your application in `views/layout.haml` as described a couple paragraphs down at http://sinatra-book.gittr.com/#templates
2. Override sinatra-authentication's `use_layout?` method as such:

   ```
   module Sinatra
     module Helpers
       def use_layout?
         false
       end
     end
   end
   ```